# How do i redirect a directory to the parent directory in htacess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this website `http://www.foo.com/bar/index.php`.  I recently moved my site FROM `foo.com/bar/index.php` TO `foo.com/index.php`

In my htaccess file, how do i write the conditions so that if any request is made from lets say `.foo.com/bar/somedirectory/somefile` REDIRECT to  `foo.com/somedirectory/somefile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the htaccess file in your document root, preferably above any rules that do routing (to `index.php`, for example), add these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/bar/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -d
RewriteRule ^/?bar/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

If you want to externally redirect the client (changing the URL in the browser's address bar), then add the `R` flag in the rule's brackets: `[L,R=301]`.

Answer (score 0):

Add below to your `foo.com/bar/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```